# when I try to run karma, 'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'chai''

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner

when I try to run Karma, `npm run karma start .\calculator.conf.js`, there is something wrong: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'chai' at node_modules/_mocha@4.0.1@mocha/mocha.js:1`, but when I run the command 'npm run mocha', It's all right.

package.json

````
```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "karma": "karma",
    "mocha": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```
````

test file

````
```

    var chai = require('chai')
      , expect = chai.expect
      , should = chai.should();
    describe('accMul', function () {
      it('should return accurate number when all the parameter are integer', function () {
        expect(22).to.equal(22)
      })
    })

```
````

the Karma config file: calculator.conf.js

````
```
config.set({
    frameworks: ['mocha'],
    files: [
      'src/*.js',
      'test/*.js'
    ],
    ...
)
```
````

I have try the command `npm install chai -g`, but It's unuseful, help!

Comment: Try installing `chai` as a dependency => `npm install --save chai`

Comment: It still appears the same errors,  It seems that mocha.js can't require 'chai' correctly, but when I run `npm run mocha`, everything is ok.